# Spresenseで動画を撮りたい

Tags: spresense, arduino

camera.inoでは、JPGをキャプチャする例が示されています。
ところで、動画を撮ることは可能なのでしょうか？
その際、音も録音することは可能なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

ちょうど少し前にAVIで動画を撮るスケッチを書いてみました。8fps程度しかできていませんが、Spresense の Arduino Camera ライブラリに手を入れればもう少しfps を出すことが可能かもしれません。残念ながら、このスケッチは音には対応していません。

```
#include <Camera.h>
#include <SDHCI.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

SDClass theSD;

/* WIDTH == 1280 (0x500) */
#define WIDTH_1 0x00
#define WIDTH_2 0x05
/* HEIGHT == 960 (0x3C0) */
#define HEIGHT_1 0xC0
#define HEIGHT_2 0x03
#define TOTAL_FRAMES 300
#define AVIOFFSET 240

unsigned long movi_size = 0;
const char avi_header[AVIOFFSET+1] = {
  0x52, 0x49, 0x46, 0x46, 0xD8, 0x01, 0x0E, 0x00, 0x41, 0x56, 0x49, 0x20, 0x4C, 0x49, 
  0x53, 0x54, 0xD0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x68, 0x64, 0x72, 0x6C, 0x61, 0x76, 0x69, 0x68, 
  0x38, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xA0, 0x86, 0x01, 0x00, 0x80, 0x66, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x64, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, WIDTH_1, WIDTH_2, 0x00, 0x00, 
  HEIGHT_1, HEIGHT_2, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4C, 0x49, 0x53, 0x54, 0x84, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x73, 0x74, 0x72, 0x6C, 0x73, 0x74, 0x72, 0x68, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x76, 0x69, 0x64, 0x73, 0x4D, 0x4A, 0x50, 0x47, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x73, 0x74, 0x72, 0x66, 0x28, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x28, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, WIDTH_1, WIDTH_2, 0x00, 0x00, HEIGHT_1, HEIGHT_2, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 0x4D, 0x4A, 0x50, 0x47, 0x00, 0x84, 0x03, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x4C, 0x49, 0x53, 0x54, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x6F, 0x64, 0x6D, 0x6C, 
  0x64, 0x6D, 0x6C, 0x68, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x64, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4C, 0x49, 
  0x53, 0x54, 0x00, 0x01, 0x0E, 0x00, 0x6D, 0x6F, 0x76, 0x69, 0x00
};

File aviFile;
String filename = "movie.avi";
uint32_t start_ms = 0;

static void inline uint32_write_to_aviFile(uint32_t v) { 
  char value = v % 0x100;
  aviFile.write(value);  v = v >> 8; 
  value = v % 0x100;
  aviFile.write(value);  v = v >> 8;
  value = v % 0x100;
  aviFile.write(value);  v = v >> 8; 
  value = v;
  aviFile.write(value);
}


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  theCamera.begin();
  theSD.begin();

  theSD.remove(filename);
  aviFile = theSD.open(filename ,FILE_WRITE);
  aviFile.write(avi_header, AVIOFFSET);

  Serial.println("Recording...");

  theCamera.setStillPictureImageFormat(
     CAM_IMGSIZE_QUADVGA_H,
     CAM_IMGSIZE_QUADVGA_V,
     CAM_IMAGE_PIX_FMT_JPG);

  start_ms = millis();
  digitalWrite(LED0 ,HIGH);
}

int loopCounter = 0;
void loop() {

  CamImage img = theCamera.takePicture();
  if (!img.isAvailable()) {
    Serial.println("faile to take a picture");
    return;
  }

  aviFile.write("00dc", 4);
  uint32_t chunk_top = aviFile.position();

  uint32_t jpeg_size = img.getImgSize();
  uint32_write_to_aviFile(jpeg_size);

  aviFile.write(img.getImgBuff() ,jpeg_size);
  movi_size += jpeg_size;

  /* Spresense's jpg file is assumed to be 16bits aligned 
   * So, there's no padding operation */

  if (++loopCounter == TOTAL_FRAMES) {
    float duration_sec = (millis() - start_ms) / 1000.0f;
    float fps_in_float = loopCounter / duration_sec;
    float us_per_frame_in_float = 1000000.0f / fps_in_float;
    uint32_t fps = round(fps_in_float);
    uint32_t us_per_frame = round(us_per_frame_in_float);

    /* overwrite riff file size */
    aviFile.seek(0x04);
    uint32_t total_size = movi_size + 12*loopCounter + 4;
    uint32_write_to_aviFile(total_size);

    /* overwrite hdrl */
    /* hdrl.avih.us_per_frame */
    aviFile.seek(0x20);
    uint32_write_to_aviFile(us_per_frame);
    uint32_t max_bytes_per_sec = movi_size * fps / loopCounter;
    aviFile.seek(0x24);
    uint32_write_to_aviFile(max_bytes_per_sec);

    /* hdrl.avih.tot_frames */
    aviFile.seek(0x30);
    uint32_write_to_aviFile(loopCounter);
    aviFile.seek(0x84);
    uint32_write_to_aviFile(fps);   

    /* hdrl.strl.list_odml.frames */
    aviFile.seek(0xe0);
    uint32_write_to_aviFile(loopCounter);
    aviFile.seek(0xe8);
    uint32_write_to_aviFile(movi_size);

    aviFile.close();

    Serial.println("Movie saved");
    Serial.println(" File size (kB): " + String(total_size));
    Serial.println(" Captured Frame: " + String(loopCounter)); 
    Serial.println(" Duration (sec): " + String(duration_sec));
    Serial.println(" Frame per sec : " + String(fps));
    Serial.println(" Max data rate : " + String(max_bytes_per_sec));

    digitalWrite(LED0, LOW);
    while(1);

  }
}
```

撮れた動画の様子などについては、次のブログで見ることができます。ご参考になれば。

SPRESENSE で AVI の動画をサポートしてみた！　
https://makers-with-myson.blog.ss-blog.jp/2019-09-30

Answer (score 2):

動きましたー！
SDカードをClass10にすると10Fpsで撮影することができました！

10:44:03.738 -> Recording...
10:44:32.998 -> Movie saved
10:44:32.998 ->  File size (kB): 32472884
10:44:32.998 ->  Captured Frame: 300
10:44:32.998 ->  Duration (sec): 29.24
10:44:33.032 ->  Frame per sec : 10
10:44:33.032 ->  Max data rate : 1082309