# Spresenseでの動画撮影について

Tags: spresense

Spresenseを用いてMP4で動画を撮影する方法はありますでしょうか．
もしあれば，サンプルコード等ご享受いただきたいです．

Comment: 重複候補: [Spresenseで動画を撮りたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/59454)